# Cython Create C Function Alias

Tags: python, c++, cython

I have two variants of a function: `void func1(double *)` and `void func2(double *)` that are externed from C++ code.

I want to be able to write a function or mapping that wraps them:

```
cdef func_alias(int choice):
   if choice == 0:
       return func1
   elif choice == 1:
       return func2
```

But compiling `Cannot convert 'void (double *) nogil' to Python object`

Alternatively I have tried using dicts which produces the same error:

```
cdef dict func_dict = {0: func1, 1: func2}
```

But I get the same error.

I am not sure if I can do something along the lines of

```
from libcpp.map import map
cdef map[int, void] func_map = {0: func1, 1: func2}
```

which results in `Cannot interpret dict as type 'map[int,void]'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `func_alias` function does not define a return type (which means it will default to a python object). Since function pointers are not a valid python object, cython gives you that error message on compilation. We can define a `ctypedef` representing a function pointer and use that as the return type instead. Here is an example that does just that:

```
ctypedef void (* double_func)(double *)

cdef void func_1(double *arg1):
    print(1, arg1[0])

cdef void func_2(double *arg1):
    print(2, arg1[0])

cdef double_func func_alias(int choice):
    if choice == 1:
        return func_1
    elif choice == 2:
        return func_2

cdef double test_input = 3.14
func_alias(1)(&test_input)
func_alias(2)(&test_input)
```

As a side note, if you only have a fixed number of potential function pointers to consider, I would consider using an enum instead for the if-statements. I can include an example of that if it would help. Let me know if anything is unclear.

**Update:**
Looking at the second part of the question, I see that you were also considering using a hashmap to map ints to function pointers. While you can't use a `dict` to do this since those can only store python objects, you can use a `map` (or `unordered_map`, which should perform slightly better). Unfortunately, you cannot use convenient python dict syntax to initialize all of the values of the dict, and instead must add items one by one. Here is that approach in action:

```
from libcpp.unordered_map cimport unordered_map

ctypedef void (* double_func)(double *)
cdef unordered_map[int, double_func] func_map
func_map[1] = func_1
func_map[2] = func_2

cdef void func_1(double *arg1):
    print(1, arg1[0])

cdef void func_2(double *arg1):
    print(2, arg1[0])

cdef double_func func_alias(int choice):
    return func_map[choice]

cdef double test_input = 3.14
func_alias(1)(&test_input)
func_alias(2)(&test_input)
```

Comment: The unordered_map is exactly what I was looking for and it worked perfectly for my case.